# How slow is is_readable()?

Tags: php, performance, file

Is it ok if I use it to check if some file exist, like 10-15 css/js/php files? This would be done on each page load.

How much would it slow it down?

Comment: Why not try it out? It's the best way to find out. My guess however is that checking for 10-15 files is not going to be a performance problem

Comment: I don't notice any difference :) But I thought some people might have experience in using this function and know better..

Comment: If you have questions about StackOverflow, they go on [meta].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming that it is local file (and not nfs mount), it won't slow anything down, and it may be even faster then issuing request to a file that is not readable. Also, `is_readable` caches the results (you cave to call `clearstatcache` if you want to dismiss the cached results). Sure, the best way to check is to profile your page after adding the `is_readable` call, but I bet it won't make any difference

Comment: does that mean that is_readable will read contents from each of those files?

Comment: no, it won't read any content. If you ask about the cache, it caches if the file is readable or not.